# drop down filtering data

Tags: reactjs, swr

I want to filter the data with a dropdown using useSWR. The `sortedOptionList` is hardcoded. Is there a way to make it more dynamic when calling the api?

https://codesandbox.io/s/weathered-wildflower-ousy1n?file=/src/App.tsx:0-1903

Answer (score 0):

There is a useful package to do this task.

[React Select](https://react-select.com/home)

Comment: Would you please take a look? I updated my codesandbox. https://codesandbox.io/s/weathered-wildflower-ousy1n?file=/src/QuestionList.tsx
It seems that there are not many examples for react-select typescript...